# Automatically find piecewize functions breakpoints?

Tags: python, convex

Let's imagine that I have an exponential function, is there a library that can find the best breakpoints and the best piecewize functions, and above all give me the coordinates of the breakpoints?

Pwlf is nice but doesn't give the breakpoints coordinates.

[image]